# unordered list change color same level only

Tags: html, css

Good day
i have this html

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav-1"> 
<li><a href="#">Loans</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Bancassurance</a> 
  <ul class="nav-2"> 
    <li><a href="#">darb</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">elem</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">ghad</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</li> 
</ul
```

im using :

```
.nav-1 li:hover a {
background:#FF0000; 
}
```

The baground is now red for each li in .nav-1  and for all  li  in .nav-2
what i want is to stop the effect of red background ==> only  .nav-1  should be red
not li and sub menu

any help or link  ?

Thank u for any help

Comment: please take a look of this        http://jsfiddle.net/sEYba/    i want to remove the red from  .nav2  , i want only to get red on the first level of this menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution - http://jsfiddle.net/sEYba/2/

Write your CSS as -

```
.nav-1 li a:hover {
  background:#FF0000;
}
.nav-2 li a:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xPzCb/)

Comment: what i want to do is when i mouse over li.nav-1 , only the current li will have red background , and after the same for .nav-2

Comment: please take a look of this        http://jsfiddle.net/sEYba/    i want to remove the red from  .nav2  , i want only to get red on the first level of this menu

Comment: @RolandFeghaly You're welcome! hope you learned the way we specify :hover in CSS .nav-2 li a:hover you were defining background to li that's why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

This should be your answer. This will make it generic and you will not have to write extra code if you add more ul inside the first one.

```
.nav-1 li:hover a {
background:#FF0000; 
}

.nav-1 li:hover ul li a {
background:none; 
}
```

Comment: what i want to do is when i mouse over li.nav-1 , only the current li will have red background , and after the same for .nav-2

Comment: please take a look of this        http://jsfiddle.net/sEYba/    i want to remove the red from  .nav2  , i want only to get red on the first level of this menu

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
.nav-1 li a:hover{
    background:#FF0000;
}
.nav-1 li li a:hover{
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: please take a look of this        http://jsfiddle.net/sEYba/    i want to remove the red from  .nav2  , i want only to get red on the first level of this menu